# connection to servlet from android

Tags: java, android, servlets

I want to connect my android application to servlet . I had this error:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.3:8081 refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:241)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:172)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:130)
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I added the two permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I can access to http://192.168.1.3:8081/Android/Login from my browser ,it works fine . But if I did the same thing from my real android device I get "coonection time out".
I  had deactivated my firewall but still same problem.

my code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    bLogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginB);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            StringBuilder reponseHttp=new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            String from="aaa",to="bbb";
            try {
                HttpGet httpGet =new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.3:8081/Android/Login?from="+from+"&to="+to);
                HttpResponse response=client.execute(httpGet); 
                //rest of code
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you tried to avoid connecting on the main thread, with something like asynctask?

Comment: no, I 'm connecting from the main thread , should I use necessary  asynctask ?

Comment: it's the recommended approach, please show more from your Logcat

Comment: on your code you have a wrong ip 198.168.1.3 (198, should be 192), i believe you just typed wrong and it was failing with 192 as well.
First of all, try to connect from a browser on the android device. If you can't, check your android IP Adress to see if it is at the same network.

Comment: @avjr , I can't connect from my device's browser .I'm connecting the phone using USb , how can i get the IP?

Comment: i dont know if its the same for all versions of android, on my device i go to wi-fi networks, press the settings button (top right), advanced wifi.

Comment: Also, did you port forward on your modem or firewall the 8081 to your ip 192.168.1.3?

Comment: @avjr device's id=192.168.23.2 , but I didn't any port forward

Comment: Make sure your mobile is connected to same wifi network, if you are hosting in localhost

Comment: you dont need port forwarding if you are connecting locally just connect to ur computer's local net best way to isolate this is to use a android virtual device and see if u csb connect to ur server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection to server process take some time. Android ,now, obliged us to use Asynctask  class and to override doInBackground() and onPostExecute() methods.
Moreover, HttpClient is now deprecated , so we shall use UrlConnection .
Hope that this post help the future visitors ...